# Displaying images in html pages in folders?

Tags: html, image

So there are lots of examples scripts for this kind of thing on the net but half of them dont work and the other half dont quite do what I want. Iv tried amending scripts etc but I cant quite get what I need, perhaps someone can point me in the right direction or give me a script that will do the job.

My problem is quite simple. I have a set of images in a directory. I want to display all those images on a web page, all at a set with. I want the script to display all images in the directory regardless how that changes. I only want jpg images displayed not gifs etc. Finally I want the file name to be displayed below each image.

So far iv managed to display all file names in a directory but not filter out the jpgs and not actually display the images as images, just list their file name.

If anyone can help me, any and all help is greatly appreciated!
Here is my piece of code

Thanks,

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section id="projects">
            <ul id="thumbs" class="portfolio">
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/1.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/1.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-1" data-type="icon">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/2.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/2.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 photography" data-id="id-2" data-type="graphic">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/3.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/3.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/4.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/4.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 photography" data-id="id-4" data-type="web">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/5.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/5.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 photography" data-id="id-5" data-type="icon">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/6.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/6.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/7.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/7.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="graphic">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="../img/works/8.jpg">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <img src="../img/works/8.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
            </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML alone can’t do that, you will need a server-side language of some sort. Please specify which one(s) you are able/wiling to use, and also modify the tags for your question accordingly.

Comment: You're showing your `HTML` code, but nowhere am I seeing any `JavaScript` or `jQuery`, which you would need. Have you made any attempts?

Comment: i have been confused i thought this can be done in html alone now i try to implement it thanks for instant help

Comment: You *can* do it with HTML alone, but it will all have to be done manually, which is *not* what your question has asked.

Comment: What do you mean by " not actually display the images as images". Are you get any error like 404 etc?

Comment: nope i am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very basic example

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="language" content="en" />  
        <meta name="description" content="" />  
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <style type="text/css">
            ul li {list-style: none; margin-bottom: 15px;}
            ul li img {display: block;}
            ul li span {display: block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

        // open this directory 
        $myDirectory = opendir("images");

        // get each entry
        while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
            $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }

        // close directory
        closedir($myDirectory);

        //  count elements in array
        $indexCount = count($dirArray);

        ?>

        <ul>

            <?php
            // loop through the array of files and print them all in a list
            for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -3);
                if ($extension == 'jpg'){ // list only jpgs
                    echo '<li><img src="images/' . $dirArray[$index] . '" alt="Image" /><span>' . $dirArray[$index] . '</span>';
                }   
            }
            ?>

        </ul>   


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this make my day it works this script works perfectly............